# ScalaFx: Event Handler with First Class Function

Tags: scala, event-handling, first-class-functions, scalafx

i try to write an event handler in a scalaFx app. I found followin solution:

```
import scalafx.scene.control.ListView
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent
import javafx.event.EventHandler

...

    val list = new ListView[String] {
        onMouseClicked = new EventHandler[MouseEvent] {
            override def handle(event: MouseEvent) {
                doSomething(event)
            }
        }
    }
```

But this seems to be very Java-style boilerplate code. Is there a way to do this with a first class function like this?

```
        onMouseClicked = (event: MouseEvent) => doSomething(event)
```

Compiler says:

> No implicit view available from javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent => scalafx.delegate.SFXDelegate[javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent] with javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent.

Answer (score 20):

When you work with ScalaFX you always need to remember to use:

```
import scalafx.Includes._
```

This will resolve the error you have. There are many examples of using event handlers the ScalaFX way, for instance here:

- [Event handling examples in ProScalaFX](https://github.com/scalafx/ProScalaFX/tree/master/src/proscalafx/ch02)
- [Event handling demos in ScalaFX-Demos](https://github.com/scalafx/scalafx/tree/master/scalafx-demos/src/main/scala/scalafx/event)
- [Event filter examples](https://github.com/scalafx/ScalaFX-Tutorials/tree/master/event-filters/src/main/scala/event_filters)

Comment: I have resolved my 4-5 error by searching and finding this same answer again & again. Thanks for reminding me to include `scalafx.Includes`