# Compile error trying to bind mouse event listener in ScalaFx

Tags: scala, event-handling, mouseevent, scalafx

I'm coding a little test application that uses the `Canvas` class in Scala with `scalafx`. The problem is with:

```
gui.canvas.handleEvent(MouseEvent.MouseClicked){
     a: MouseEvent => {
          println("Mouse pos:" + a.sceneX+ "  " + a.sceneY)
     }      
}
```

Throwing the error:

```
[error] E:\dev\sg\src\main\scala\Test.scala:27: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scalafx.scene.input.MouseEvent => Unit
[error]  required: _2.HandlerMagnet[javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent,?] 
where val _2: scalafx.scene.canvas.Canvas
[error]       a: MouseEvent => {
[error]                     ^
```

I don't get why this exact same snippet compiles when it appears in the method `setupGraphics` but NOT in when it's in the `Main` object's code.

BTW, having browsed quite a bit of ScalaFX code, I'm getting a bit dizzy because I've seen lots different ways to bind to an event, there's [the one I'm using](https://github.com/scalafx/scalafx/blob/master/scalafx-demos/src/main/scala/scalafx/event/RectangleDrawingDemo.scala), [setting the onMouseClicked variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21836133/scalafx-event-handler-with-first-class-function) (with and without a first class function), [using filterEvent](https://github.com/scalafx/ScalaFX-Tutorials/blob/master/event-filters/src/main/scala/event_filters/DraggablePanelsExample.scala). Also, for each you can use an anonymous function or create an event handler object.

Of all those, this is the only one that worked in this example; trying to create an `EventHandler[MouseEvent]` and override `handle()` also fails in this case.

I'm using Scala 2.10.5

**Full Source:**

```
object Test {
  import scalafx.Includes._
  import scalafx.application.JFXApp
  import scalafx.application.JFXApp.PrimaryStage
  import scalafx.stage.Stage

  import scalafx.scene.Scene
  import scalafx.scene.canvas.Canvas
  import scalafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext

  import scalafx.scene.input.MouseEvent
  import scalafx.event.EventHandler



  class GUI(val canvas:Canvas
    ,val stage: Stage
    ,val gc: GraphicsContext){}

  object Main extends JFXApp {

    var gui=setupGraphics()

    gui.canvas.handleEvent(MouseEvent.MouseClicked){
      a: MouseEvent => {
        println("Mouse pos:" + a.sceneX+ "  " + a.sceneY)
      }
    }

    def setupGraphics():GUI={
      val canvas = new Canvas(400, 400)
      canvas.translateX=0
      canvas.translateY=0
      val gc = canvas.graphicsContext2D

      canvas.handleEvent(MouseEvent.MouseClicked){
        a: MouseEvent => {
          println("Mouse pos:" + a.sceneX+ "  " + a.sceneY)
        }
      }

      stage = new PrimaryStage {
        title = "asd"
        height = 600
        width = 800
        scene=new Scene{content=canvas}
      }

      return new GUI(canvas,stage,gc)
    }    
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to me like a bug in Scala compiler, especially that you can correct this by using an intermediate variable for `canvas` without modifying anything else. Instead of calling `gui.canvas.handleEvent`, first assign `canvas` to a variable then call `handleEvent` on that:

```
var gui=setupGraphics()
val canvas = gui.canvas
canvas.handleEvent(MouseEvent.MouseClicked){
  a: MouseEvent => {
    println("Mouse pos:" + a.sceneX+ "  " + a.sceneY)
  }
}
```

Comment: That's great Jarek! Although I don't think it's a bug in the compiler. I guess I'm not grokking the type system enough and it's a subtle type-related bug.